# Can I use the re library with Buildozer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, buildozer, python-re

I made a simple GUI application with Kivy and it uses `re.split()` at some point. I could make a loop instead of using the `re.split()` function, but it would be less idiomatic, I think.

When I tried compiling the program into a .apk with Buildozer, I had an error after a while and the first error I could see was that it couldn't find the `re` module. I saw online that you can't really use every single python library because there needs to be a recipe for it, but on the [list](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes), there is 'regex'. Now, there isn't a 'regex' library, so I thought that would be `re`.

Is the error coming from somewhere else or is it because I use `re`?

Comment: Actually, there is a Python module called `regex` - it's an advanced replacement for the standard `re` module.

Comment: @jasonharper Weird... I checked the other day by trying `pip install regex` and I got an error saying that regex isn't a valid module name. But now I tried again and I could actually install it. I'll try again with `regex` instead of `re`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jasonharper mentioned, there is actually a `regex` module, which has also a `regex.split()` and a `regex.compile()`. Using `regex` instead of `re` fixed the Buildozer error.